# PrimeReact DataTable presort on a Column with sortFunction

Tags: sorting, datatable, primereact

I have been trying to set a presort similarly to this: https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/datatable/sort

The problem I am facing is that I would like to sort on render by a column which has a sortFunction defined by me.

I have a working sortFunction, but if I give the DataTable a sortField, it does not use it.
[On render the nulls are in front, which is the default sort of sortable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLWfW.png) but
[clicking the header uses the proper sortFunction, which sorts alpahabetically and sends nulls to the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvNI.png)

Is it possible to solve this somehow or should I let the presorting go?

Edit: I presorted the data and gave it to the DataTable that way, so it works but it is far from elegant, also it does not show the column to have the sorted arrows on render, but it might be helpful for someone:

```
const  dataTableSortFunction  =  (value:  any[])  =>  (event:  ColumnSortParams):  any[]  =>  {
    return  [...value].sort((data1,  data2)  =>  {
        const  value1  =  data1[event.field];
        const  value2  =  data2[event.field];
        if  (value1  ==  null  &&  value2  ==  null)  return  0;
        if  (value2  ==  null)  return  -1;
        if  (value1  ==  null)  return  1;
        if  (typeof  value1  ===  "string"  &&  typeof  value2  ===  "string")
            return  value1.localeCompare(value2)  *  event.order;
         if  (value1  <  value2)  return  -1  *  event.order;
        if  (value1  >  value2)  return  1  *  event.order;
        return  0;
    });
};
const  myProductSort  =  dataTableSortFunction(products);
const  preSortedProducts  =  myProductSort({ field:  "category", order:  -1  });
```

...

```
<DataTable  value={preSortedProducts} className="p-datatable-sm">
    <Column  field="code"  header="Code"  sortable></Column>
    <Column  field="name"  header="Name"  sortable></Column>
    <Column
        field="category"
        header="Category"
        sortable
        sortFunction={myProductSort}
    ></Column>
    <Column  field="quantity"  header="Quantity"  sortable></Column>
    <Column  field="price"  header="Price"  sortable></Column>
</DataTable>
```